# Seemingly impossible limit problem

Tags: limits

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{10} + (x+2)^{10} + (x+3)^{10} + \dots + (x+100)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}$$

I was gliding through limit problems until I got to this bad boy... The only thing that I really thought of after looking at this limit for some time is that I can take out $\ x $ on top. That doesn't really solve anything...

Comment: Hint: Compare the degrees and leading coefficients of the polynomials that you'd get if you expanded both numerator and denominator.

Comment: As $x \to \infty$, $(x+n)^{10} \to x^{10}$. You can basically start ignoring constants that are added.

Comment: replace $(x+1)^{10}$ with $x^{10}$ and do the same for every binomial in the numerator then compute the limit. You can also split into sum of limits if that's easier for you

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I'm confused, how is that possible?

Comment: @Vasya same thing with Mohammed

Comment: @tariktrokic: start with computing limit of $\frac{(x+1)^{10}}{x^{10}}$ and you'll see how

Comment: @tariktrokic If $n$ is a constant, the expansion of $(x+n)^{10}$ has only one term of degree $10$, namely $x^{10}$ by the binomial theorem. Note that when computing the limits of rational functions to infinity, only the terms in the top and bottom with the highest degree matters.

Comment: Would you mind writing your problem in the question text? This way others might find it later (you can't search for pictures).

Comment: It may be easier to see this way: $\frac{(x+a)^{10}}{x^{10}}=\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^{10}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a \in \{ 1, \dots, 100 \}$. Now look at $\frac{(x+a)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}$. You'll notice that the leading coefficient of $(x+a)^{10}$ is 1. The rest of the polynomial $(x+a)^{10}$ are terms of smaller degree. Therefore they won't matter for the limit:

Let $(x+a)^{10} = x^{10} + a_9 x^9 + \dots +a_1 x + a_0$ for some $a_9, \dots ,a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Now you have:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x+a)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{10} + a_9 x^9 + \dots +a_1 x + a_0}{x^{10}+10^{10}} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 + a_9 \frac{x^9}{x^{10}} + \dots + a_1 \frac{x}{x^{10}} + \frac{a_0}{x^{10}}}{1+\frac{10^{10}}{x^{10}}} = 1$$
[You have leading coefficient 1 in the numerator and 1 in the denominator therfore your expression goes to one].

Now you have:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x+1)^{10} + \dots + (x+100)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} \frac{(x+k)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x+k)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} 1 = 100$$

Comment: There was no need to expand $(x+a) ^{10}$. Instead write $\dfrac{(x+a) ^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}=\dfrac{(1+(a/x))^{10}}{1+(10/x)^{10}}$ and this tends to $(1+0)^{10}/(1+0^{10})=1$.